# How to use /k to keep a command prompt shortcut from closing?

Tags: command-line, shortcuts, ping

I am trying to make a shortcut that will run the following command with the following switches. The window closes before the command can run long enough. I want to know where to put the /k in the target box of the shortcut to keep the windows from closing. (I think it is /k but maybe its something else).

```
ping XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -t -l 25565
```

My target field looks like this:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE" /k 10.98.56.1 -t -I 25565
```

But I don't know where the /k is supposed to go (if it is /k). can someone rewrite this with the correct syntax for me?

Comment: Note: `-I` is not a valid option for Ping in Windows, and Ping's `-i` (which _is_ valid, it's TTL) only accepts a maximum value of 255.

Answer (score 2):

The `/k` parameter needs to be passed to the terminal process (`cmd.exe`).  So, your shortcut should look like this:

```
%COMSPEC% /k C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -t -I 25565
```

Note: `%COMSPEC%` will resolve to `cmd.exe`

Comment: To be pedantic it is `%ComSpec%` ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `/k` argument you mentioned is for `cmd.exe`, not `ping`.  So you have to call:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "c:\windows\system32\ping.exe" -t -I 255 192.168.1.1
```

The `-t` argument specifies that you'll ping until cancelled, and the `-I` parameter specifies a TTL (Time-To-Live).  The maximum value of this field is 255 per TCP specification.

Before I realized the `/k` argument was for `cmd.exe`, I wrote this answer out using batch files.  It might be informative and it's just another way to get the job done, so I'll leave that in case it's worthwhile.

---

Batch file example 1:

```
@ECHO OFF
ping -t -I 255 %1
pause
exit
```

Then you could call that batch file with the shortcut:

```
"c:\folder\batchfile.bat" 192.168.1.1
```

Of course you'd substitute the drive, folder, batch file name, and IP address.

You could also batch a series of pings using a structure like this:

```
@echo off
:loop
cls
ping -n 10 -I 255 %1
timeout 5
goto :loop
```

Which uses the `-n` argument to ping 10 times, then does a timeout for 5 seconds before starting over with another batch of 10.